# Add slideUp animation with jQuery in the existing method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to animate the multistep form with jQuery sliudeUp animation but unable to understand that how it will be possible to put the jQuery sliudeUp animate method in my existing code to animate my form with on click event.
index.html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <div class="container">
          <form>
      
            <div class="step step-1 active">
              <div class="form-group">
              
                <input type="text" id="firstName" name="first-name" placeholder="Enter Your Name" style="background-color: lightgray;">
              </div>
              
              <button type="button" class="next-btn">Get Started</button>
            </div>
            <!--Step 02-->
            <div class="step step-2 " >
              <div class="form-group">
                
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" style="background-color:lightgrey">
              </div>
              
             
              <button type = "button" class="next-btn">Next</button>
            </div>
      <!--Step 03-->
            <div class="step step-3 ">
              
              <div class="form-group">
               
                <input type="text" id="postCode" name="post-code" placeholder="Select a time for your free Training" style="background-color: lightgrey">
                <input type="datetime-local">
              </div>
            
              <button type="submit" class="submit-btn">Get Free Training + Check List</button>
            </div>
      
          </form>
        </div>
      </section>

      <script src ="./main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

main.js file.

```
const steps = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('form .step'));
const nextBtn = document.querySelectorAll('form .next-btn');
const form = document.querySelector('form' );

nextBtn.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    changeStep('next');
  })
})

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const inputs = [];
  form.querySelectorAll('input').for Each(input => {
    const { name, value } = input;
    inputs. Push({name , value})
  });
  console.log(inputs)
  form. Reset();
  let index = 0;
  const active = document.querySelector('.active');
  index = steps.indexOf(active);
  steps[index].classList.remove('active');
  steps[0].classList.add('active');
})
/*Change Step Function*/

function changeStep(btn){
  let index = 0;
  const active = document.querySelector('form .step.active');
  index = steps.indexOf(active);
  steps[index].classList.remove('active');
  if(btn === 'next'){
    index++;
  
  }
  steps[index].classList.add('active');
  console.log(index)
}
```

style.css File

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  section {

    min-height:100vh;
    width:100%;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    
  }
  .container{
    width:90%;
    max-width:400px;  
    background-color:white;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #00000020;
    padding:20px;
    border-radius:8px;
  }
.step{
    display:none;
}
.step.active{
    display:block;
}
.form-group{
    width:100%;
    margin-top:20px;
}
.form-group input{
    width:100%;
    border:1.5px solid grey;
    padding:5px;
    font-size:18px;
    margin-top:5px;
    border-radius: 0px;
}
button.next-btn{
    float:right;
    margin-top:20px;
    padding:10px 30px;
    background-color: blue;
    color:white;
    

}
button.submit-btn{
    float:right;
    margin-top:20px;
    padding:10px 30px;
    background-color: blue;
    color:white;
}
```

Please help me to put query slideUp animation with onclick event.
Thank you.

Comment: `Push` should be `push`. JS is case-sensitive.

Comment: There's no jQuery code in your JavaScript. Where is your attempt to do this?

Comment: You don't need jQuery to produce a simple slide up animation...

Comment: @HereticMonkey,plese guide me how  can I add simple slide UP method?

Comment: @Barmar <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   
   $('#btnSlideUp').click(function(){
    $('#box').slideUp(500);
   });
   
 </script>

Comment: I  want to add slide up method to animate slide up

Comment: Edit the question to show your code. But I don't see any reason why that shouldn't work. Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: There's no `btnSlideUp` or `box` in the HTML. It seems like the code you've posted has nothing to do with the question you're asking.

Comment: Please look the function changeStep I added there

Comment: /*Change Step Function*/

function changeStep(btn){
  let index = 0;
  const active = document.querySelector('form .step.active');
  index = steps.indexOf(active);
  steps[index].classList.remove('active');
  if(btn === 'next'){
   
   
 //I want add this function onclick event when we click the button next slide will show with slide up animation.  
   $(document).ready(function(){
   
   $('#btnSlideUp').click(function(){
    $('#box').slideUp(500);
   });
   
   
    index++;
  
  }
  steps[index].classList.add('active');
  console.log(index)
}

Comment: @BarmarPlease replace this code in my change step method.I am trying when I click on the button next form should appear with slideup animation